# How to fix 'launch.json' error when debugging Azure Function locally using Azurite?

Tags: python, azure, debugging, azure-functions, launch

I am currently developing a small time-triggered Azure Function App to retrieve files from a SFTP Server. To debug the code I am using the azurite storage emulator. The set up and running of the emulator worked well. However, I receive a Visual Studio Code error saying that the program can not be launched and the code does not compile (see image below). I am using the default launch.json that was provided via the Azure extension:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
  "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
 }
]
}
```

The error is only received as a pop-up. Please have a look at the following picture to see the error and terminal output:

[image: Error]

The error says: "request":"attach" requires either "connect", "listen", or "processid". I tried multiple options on how to make it work including launch.json as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/851). The error will go away, but the program will simply not run.

Do you have suggestions or a tutorial on how to fix this ?

Note that I use python 3.8 and Azure Functions version 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what helped in the end was to:

1. delete the .vscode directory of your project
2. close VS Code and then re-open VS Code
3. rebuild the .vscode directory (you should be prompted to do so)